# Matlab efficient matrix operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices `A` size **TxN** and `B` size **NxT**.

For an optimization algorithm I need to vectorize `B`, so `C = B(:)` is **NTx1**

All I want is to do something like `W = A*X*C` such that the vector `W` obeys

`W(i) = A(i,:) * B(:,i)` scalar product between the vectors at time `i` of `A(i,:)` and  `B(:,i)`.

Or something similar. I want to keep an expression like (matrix products including `A`)`*C` so I can easily differentiate

Thanks for your help,
Much appreciated

Comment: *I need to ...*, *All I want ...*, *I want to ...* but no question.  What is stopping you from satisfying your own wants and needs ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
W = sum(A.*B.',2);
```

Where `.'` makes sure you do not take the hemitian conjugate. If you have any questions, feel free to comment and ask.